# Why am I getting different results in R for loop print vs write.csv

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I am attempting to write my first for loop in R.   The loop should read a list of species, determine the AUC and Kappa values for each species and then write the data for a .csv file.

For now I've left out the Kappa part of the code to simplify.  The code runs fine but the output I get to the csv file is the last species on my list and the corresponding AUC repeated 15 times.

Instead if I run print(i) and print(AUC) I get a list of each species and the corresponding AUC.  I don't understand why `print` and `write.csv` are not giving me the same results.

```
setwd("Y:/HModel/Maxent/MaxentOutputs/allspp 11-28")
splist <-c( "pomatomus_saltatrix",
            "stenotomus_chrysops",
            "illex_illecebrosus",
            "lophius_americanus",
            "squalus_acanthias",
            "scophthalmus_aquosus",
            "paralichthys_dentatus",
            "helicolenus_dactylopterus",
            "merluccius_albidus",
            "merluccius_bilinearis",
            "urophycis_chuss",
            "cynoscion_regalis",
            "pollachius_virens",
            "urophycis_tenuis",
            "tautogolabrus_adspersus")

n = rep(NA, length(splist))
AUCandKAPPA = data.frame(sppocean=n, AUC=n, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in splist) {
  presence_csv <- paste(i,"0", "samplePredictions.csv", sep = "_")
  background_csv <- paste(i, "0", "backgroundPredictions.csv", sep = "_")

  presence <- read.csv(presence_csv)
  background <- read.csv(background_csv)

  pp <- presence$Logistic.prediction # get the column of predictions
  testpp <- pp[presence$Test.or.train=="test"] # select only test points
  trainpp <- pp[presence$Test.or.train=="train"] # select only test points
  bb <- background$Logistic

  combined <- c(testpp, bb) # combine into a single vector
  label <- c(rep(1,length(testpp)),rep(0,length(bb))) # labels: 1=present, 0=random
  pred <- prediction(combined, label) # labeled predictions
  perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr") # True / false positives, for ROC curve
  AUC <-performance(pred, "auc")@y.values[[1]] # Calculate the AUC

  # fill in diagnostics
  AUCandKAPPA$sppocean = i 
  AUCandKAPPA$AUC = AUC
  print(i)
  print(AUC)

  # write AUC and kappa to excel file
  write.csv(AUCandKAPPA, file="kappa_sp1-28.csv")
}
```

I tried changing the following lines but I get the error

```
# fill in diagnostics
  AUCandKAPPA$sppocean[i] = i
  AUCandKAPPA$AUC[i] = AUC

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "sppocean", value = c("15", "pomatomus_saltatrix" : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted change is a step in the right direction.  You've noticed that your loop is overwriting the results at each iteration.  But since you are controlling your loop via the character strings in `splist`, you cannot index the data frame `AUCandKappa` by using `i`.  Perhaps control your loop with a numeric index:

```
for(i in 1:length(splist)) {}
```

Adjusting any code that relied on the characters from `splist` being assigned to `i` so that it extracts from `splist` via `splist[i]`.

and then assign the results to your table:

```
# fill in diagnostics
AUCandKAPPA[i, "sppocean"] <- splist[i]
AUCandKAPPA[i, "AUC"] <- AUC
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm still learning how for loops work, can you explain why I cannot index the data frame 'AUCandKappa' by using 'i'?

Comment: Sure, it's possible to use `i` as you have it, but would require an adjustment to the data frame you defined.  Specifically, you would need to add row names to the data frame via `row.names(AUCandKAPPA) <- splist`, and I think that would allow you to use the fix that you originally tried.  In terms of bigger picture R, Hadley Wickham describes subsetting much better than I ever would here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html